# How do I execute a jquery command on the last select box in a form?

Tags: jquery

My goal here is to add a new select box whenever the latest select box is no longer empty.  My jquery command will look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $.get("get_exercise_list", function(data, status){
                //Create new select box
            });
        });
    });
```

But instead of 'select' I need to use the id of the latest select box. I imagine I will use some sort of counter and create IDs for each select box such as "select1" "select2" etc.  But I am not sure how I would keep track of that portion within the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could do using this:

```
$('select:last').on('change', function() {
  // run something here
})
```

Or this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select:last', function() {
  // run something here
})
```

e.g.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#first-container > select:last', function() {
  console.log('First container - el:' + this.id)
})

$(document).on('change', '#second-container > select:last', function() {
  console.log('Second container - el:' + this.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first-container">

  <select id="fs1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="fs2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="fs3">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div id="second-container">
  <select name="ss1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="ss2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="ss3">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a good idea but the :last selector only works for the absolute last element on the page right?  I am actually going to be be using this logic in multiple spots on one page.

Comment: Yes, but you could be more specific, like adding the container div to the selector.

Comment: I will have to look into how exactly that works but that sounds like it will be the best solution.  Thanks!